# Trouble understanding Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am having trouble grasping the Moq framework. From the Moq website they give this example ...

```
// Assumptions:
public interface IFoo {
   public bool DoSomething(string);
   public bool TryParse(string, out string));
}

var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

What is the Moq setup doing here?

```
// out arguments
var outString = "ack";
// TryParse will return true, and the out argument will return "ack", lazy evaluated
mock.Setup(foo => foo.TryParse("ping", out outString)).Returns(true);
```

Same question here .. what is being setup?

Does anyone know of a guide to Moq that maybe goes more in depth? I read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248944/287793) where the book [The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET](http://www.manning.com/osherove/) is recommended but the book is pretty old and is out of print.

Comment: There was a [second edition](https://www.manning.com/books/the-art-of-unit-testing-second-edition) of Art of Unit Testing a couple of years ago, which is still in print AFAIK

Comment: @NikolaiDante - Wow! Didn't even check for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general background on mocking, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666006/1698557) does a pretty good job explaining it and why you might want to use it in your unit tests.

Specifically, Moq is a library that allows you to easily creates mock object and control their behavior.  It's easiest to describe with examples, so let's look at your first code sample:

```
public interface IFoo {
   public bool DoSomething(string);
   public bool TryParse(string, out string));
}

/* 1 */ var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
/* 2 */ mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

Line 1 creates a *mock implementation* of the `IFoo` interface.  Under the covers, Moq is using the [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) library to create a concrete implementation of `IFoo` on the fly, and then wrapping it in its own `Mock` class so we can configure its behavior.

So now that we have a mock object, we'll frequently need to configure how it responds to having its methods invoked.  That way, we can test how our system under test will react to it.  The `Setup` method on line 2 does exactly this, telling our mock object to return `true` when `DoSomething` is called with a parameter equal to `"ping"`.  Imagine you were using this mock to test a class like below:

```
public class TestObject 
{
    public string TestMethod(IFoo foo)
    {
        if (foo.DoSomething("ping"))
            return "ping";
        else if (foo.DoSomething("pong"))
            return "pong";
        return "blah";
    }
}
```

To get complete test coverage, you'd want an implementation of `IFoo` that can:

1. return `true` for `"ping"` in one test
2. return `true` for `"pong"` in another test
3. return `false` for any argument in the last test

You *could* create your own mock object that has this behavior, e.g.:

```
public class MockFoo : IFoo
{
    string trueValue;

    public MockFoo(string trueValue)
    {
        this.trueValue = trueValue;
    }

    public bool DoSomething(string value)
    {
        return value == trueValue;
    }
}
```

But that's kind of a pain when you have complicated logic, multiple parameters, or many dependencies; it just doesn't scale well.  This is where mock objects and Moq can make things easy.  The same setup in Moq for the three tests is:

1. ```
   mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
   ```
2. ```
   mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("pong")).Returns(true);
   ```
3. ```
   mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
   ```

In my opinion, that's simpler and more expressive about how you expect your `IFoo` dependency to behave.

As for a guide, I think you'd be better off with a guide to mocking in general rather than a Moq-specific guide.  Moq is just a library that makes using mock objects easier, and the [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) is a pretty good reference for the mechanics of using Moq.  There are dozens of mocking tutorials and guides, just look for some.  And remember, it didn't really "click" for me until I started using them.  Find a [coding kata](http://codekata.com/kata/kata01-supermarket-pricing/) and try mocking out for yourself!

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you very much for taking the time to put it all together! I will take your advice on looking for more general "mocking" tutorials.