# how to pass injected service in controller when using xunit test

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I have dot net core (v5) web api porject.

I want to make a `Xunit test`  for testing my web api.

I have a `UsersController` for `CRUD` . in my Constructor i have 4 input as shown below:

```
public UsersController(AppDbContext _appDbContext, IMapper _mapper, IOptions<SieveOptions> sieveOptions, SeiveProcessorService sieveProcessorService) : base(_appDbContext, _mapper)
{
      _sieveProcessorService = sieveProcessorService;
      _sieveOptions = sieveOptions.Value;
}
```

`SeiveProcessorService` its a `Service` in my project.

I can pass three input in my test unit but i can't pass last input.

i dont know how to send to controller

my test code is :

```
        [Fact]
        public void Test_GetList()
        {
            using (var context = new AppDbContext(ContextOptions))
            {

                //auto mapper configuration
                var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile(null));
                });
                var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();

                //
                SieveOptions sieveOptions = new SieveOptions() { 
                    CaseSensitive = false,
                    DefaultPageSize = 50,
                    MaxPageSize = 500,
                    ThrowExceptions = true,
                };
                IOptions<SieveOptions> options = Options.Create(sieveOptions);

                // Arrange
                var controller = new UsersController(context, mapper, options,????);

                // Act
                var result = controller.GetList(null);

                // Assert
                var viewResult = Assert.IsType<IResult>(result);
                Assert.Null(viewResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how can send fourth input?

Comment: Slap an interface on it, change the constructor to accept the interface, and mock the interface?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar can you explain ?

Comment: In addition to Maruf's answer, you'll want to take a look at mocking libraries such as Moq, NSubstitute, and FakeItEasy. There are others too, but Moq is the most popular. You should to substitute a fake (mocked) `SeiveProcessorService` which interfaces make it easy to do. By using `ISeiveProcessorService` instead of `SeiveProcessorService`, the mocking library can easily generate its own implementations for `ISeiveProcessorService`'s methods, which allows you to test things without needing all the dependency tree (which would be integration testing anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble understanding Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683150/trouble-understanding-moq)

Answer (score 1):

Create `ISeiveProcessorService` intrerface and `mock` it in your unit testing.

```
public interface ISeiveProcessorService
{
    void A();
}

public class SeiveProcessorService : ISeiveProcessorService
{
    // implement interface methods
    public void A()
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

in order to use `Moq` you need to install and import namespace.
And in your test method:

```
Mock<ISeiveProcessorService> _mockSeiveProcessorService new Mock<ISeiveProcessorService>();
  
// set up moq  
_mockSeiveProcessorService.Setup(e => e.A()).Returns("Something");
                      
var controller = new UsersController(context, mapper, options,_mockSeiveProcessorService.Object);
```

Comment: how can mock the interface in unit testing?

Comment: you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/

Comment: can you explain more? i dont understand

Comment: yes, wait for a moment

Comment: how can use in `var controller = new UsersController(context, mapper, options,????);`?

Comment: sorry for delay, your code breaks some `OOP` and `SOLID` priciples. And I wanted to post my recomendations, if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245193/discussion-between-mhsankar-and-maruf).

Comment: Note: other mocking frameworks exist.

Comment: @JHBonarius help me . how can new from controller?